# Не запускаются программы в Intelij idea

Tags: java

Даже самые примитивные проги не запускаются:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть подозрения, что это связано с папкой out(ее я не наблюдаю), зато в настройках она указана:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: перенеси папку проекта туда, где в названиях папок нет русских букв

Comment: @Эникейщик, 2020 год на дворе, а у джавы всё ещё проблемы с юникодом?

Comment: @Qwertiy не могу знать

Answer (score 2):

Если вы посмотрите в настройках проекта (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S), вы должны увидеть структуру модуля. Если вместо этого вы видите «Ничего не видно», сделайте следующее:

В **Project Structure** -> **Modules**
нажмите кнопку **"+"**,
нажмите **Enter** (так как по какой-то странной причине он не позволяет мне нажимать **"New Module"**)
Во всплывающем окне нажмите **"..."** рядом с Корнем содержимого, найдите свою корневую папку и выберите ее.
Нажмите **ОК**
игнорировать любые предупреждения, в которых говорится, что имя уже используется (или в связи с этим)

Comment: Проверил, вроде все ок, там походу проблема с папкой out. Чекни обновленный вопрос

Answer (score 1):

У вас название одной из папок на русском языке, вероятнее всего IDE ругается по этому поводу. Попробуйте создать проект в папке, путь к которой будет содержать только английские символы.

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло